# Do you need military power when using the Rebel Sneak Attack to settle an additional military world?

Tags: race-for-the-galaxy

The card *Rebel Sneak Attack*, among its other powers, grants the ability to discard itself from the tableau to allow you to place an additional military world.

**Do you need to have sufficient military strength to take over the world, or do you get it for zero cost?** If you need the military, then this card seems like a weaker version of Improved Logistics, for only one lower cost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still need to have sufficient military power to place the world. Nothing about the placement text implies that ordinary requirements are suspended. Indeed, the [game designer says](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/535171/can-you-takeover-then-rebel-sneak-attack-a-militar) (emphasis mine):

> Yes. And, just like IL doing a normal Settle after a declared
>   takeover, the player doing this declares this additional settlement
>   during their powers and payment step, **discards RSA, pumps Military if
>   needed, etc.**, and then delays the resolution of this additional
>   settlement until the pending takeover is resolved. If the declared
>   takeover fails, then the RSA additional placement is lost, RSA is
>   still used up, etc., with the world itself then being returned to its
>   owner's hand.
>
> Exactly the same restrictions as IL after a takeover apply to an RSA
>   additional settlement after a takeover, along with the additional
>   restrictions noted on the RSA power.

Regarding your Improved Logistics comment: Improved Logistics is a bit of an aberration - it's [really, really good](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/455124/improved-logistics-broken-card). But this card allows takeovers, which is a two card swing (from them to you), which you seem to be discounting. Also, consider that Rebel Sneak Attack would be *extremely* powerful if it allowed placement of any military world for free (think high value Rebel Homeworld, etc.).

Comment: I forgot about takeovers - my gaming group plays entirely without them. Yes, it means that several cards are only good as discard fodder.  (We also occasionally play without the prestige-gives-you-cards-and/or-VP-every-turn rules, to slightly nerf the military track.)